# DOS ASCII Code pages

Tags: ascii, data-conversion, utf, ebcdic

I have a legacy system that is using one EBCDIC to ASCII conversion table.  The writer probably did not know that there are multiple code pages for ASCII and EBCDIC.  There are extended and accented letters that are not converted properly and I can fix those according to the code pages in use.

I'm asking if anybody knows a single place where I can look at as much code pages as possible to try and figure out the table that was used for conversion.  Looking through multiple Wikipedia pages for each code page is too slow and possibly error prone.

Comment: Nota bene: ASCII is *only* defined for the first 128 characters. There are no “multiple ASCII code pages”. There's ASCII and a whole bunch of derived ones that are supersets of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) has a wide variety of [tables](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/data/trunk/charset/data/ucm/) for converting various EBCDIC and ASCII versions into Unicode,.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tables. If you handle documents of various nations/regions, you have to use multiple tables.

Most of Europian lanuages may be coverd by http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp00500.html.

The code table may be found at ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00500.pdf

If you specify what the languages  you try to handle by your code, more suitable and specific answer may come.